# An English version Borok's work on finite-infinite systems of ordinary differential equations

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cauchy-problem

I am looking for the English translation of the paper by V. M. Borok (originally in Russian)
[The Cauchy problem for finite-infinite systems of linear differential equations](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ivm&paperid=6842&option_lang=eng). This work is about the Cauchy problem $x'=Ax$ where $A$ is an infinite matrix, with possibly unbounded coefficients, whose $i$-th row has only a finite number of elements.

[Checking here: ZentralMath](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0574.34002) says that the English translation is at the journal "Sov. Math. 26, No.7, 1-11 (1982); translation from Izv. Vyssh. Uchebn. Zaved., Mat. 1982, No.7(242), 3-10 (1982)." A search at my university library led me to "Soviet Mathematics Doklady", vol. 26, 1982, Tom 265-267, but it is not this one. I also looked at Turpion.org and at Izvestiya: Mathematics of IOPScience, with no success.

What is the complete name of the journal in English? Is there an electronic copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Soviet mathematics" is a publication which translated Russian papers from various journals which were not translated cover-to cover. This publication was quite expensive and few libraries subsctibed it. Selected papers from Izvestiia Vysshikh Uchebnykh Zavedenii, where this paper is published were translated. Most university libraries that I know have the service which is called Interlibrary Loan. Just ask your libarian. They will order a photocopy or a journal issue from another library.

Comment: The photocopy finally arrived, through interlibrary loan. Thanks UFR Math-Info from Université de Strasbourg!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, the titles of the two journals you refer to
are [Izvestiya Vysshikh Uchebnykh Zavedenii, Matematika](https://zbmath.org/journals/?q=se:00000120)
and [Soviet Mathematics](https://zbmath.org/journals/?q=se:00000797) (the latter without appended "Doklady").